# #PythonBasemap How to plot data from nc4 on basemap with 'for loop'?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to plot nc4 data in geographical coordinate (lat,lon) on basemap with 'for loop'. I attached my code below.

```
files = [file for file in glob.glob('*.nc4')]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3)
axs = axs.ravel()

for i in range(len(files)):
   data = nc.Dataset(files[i],'r')
   zdata = data.variables['Z'][:,:,:]
   var_lon = data.variables['lon'][:]
   var_lat = data.variables['lat'][:]

   X, Y = np.meshgrid(var_lon,var_lat)

   map = Basemap()
   map.drawcoastlines()
    
   im = axs[i].contourf(X,Y,Zdata)

   axs[i].set_xlabel('Longitude (deg)')
   axs[i].set_ylabel('Lattitude (deg)')
   clb = fig.colorbar(im, ax= axs[i],orientation="vertical", pad=0.03, aspect=16 )
   clb.set_label('Z (%s)'%(data.variables['Z'].units),size=10,rotation=90,labelpad=10)'

plt.show()
```

What I got from my code is it show the basemap just only the last one. I expected the basemap gonna show every map that I plot.
[image]

Any comments are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying an axes (here `ax=axs[i]`) as a parameter in `Basemap()` in each iteration, the default/current axes takes effect on that line of code. In the end, the process evaluation is wrapped up at `plt.show()`, so that, the last axes which become the current axes is the only one that has coastlines plotted.

To get it right, just change the line of code:-

```
map = Basemap()
```

to

```
map = Basemap(ax=axs[i])
```

and the output plot should be as expected.